# PostgreSQL said: permission denied for schema

Tags: ruby, postgresql, postico

I have a multi-tenant PostgreSQL db on a Ruby on Rails app, and when I try to access to tables on some schemas on Postico, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load table schema.
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: permission denied for schema coaching
```

I tried to run: `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "lacerba-api" TO "postico7"` but I get `ERROR:  permission denied for schema lacerba-api`

Of course my user have writing permission on the db.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You need to log in as someone with the power to do the grant.  Like the schema's owner, or a superuser.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your user doesn't have permission to read tables in the coaching schema. You can try granting your user permission to read tables in that schema:

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA coaching TO postico7

Comment: My bad, I copied the wrong schema name. However, it does not work neither with GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA coaching TO postico7